# Styling with style-like attribute in compound components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

There are some custom components which wrap more than one element, but allow you to style them individually with multiple style-like attributes.

For example in react-native-elements there's Button: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html

The above can accept `buttonStyle` and `containerStyle`.

As far as I know, styled-components decorate your component with `style`. How do I make it target an attribute I'd give it e.g. `buttonStyle` or `containerStyle`?